# Repositório Genérico com Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, design-pattern, dapper, repository

estou fazendo uma aplicação de teste onde quero ver a performance e aprender sobre como criar um repositório genérico com Dapper, bem tenho alguma experiência quando criei um repositório genérico, porém usando EF6, tentando usar a mesma lógica fiz a construção quase da mesma forma as classes principais, são as seguintes:

Interface IRepositorio

```
public interface IRepositorio<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    dynamic Adicionar(TEntity entity, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null);
    bool Atualizar(TEntity entity, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null);
    bool Deletar(TEntity entity, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null);
    TEntity ObterPorId(int id, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> ObterTodos(IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> ObterPor(object where = null, object order = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null);

}
```

A classe Repositorio que implementa a minha interface:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepositorio<TEntity>, IDisposable where TEntity : class
{
    public IDbConnection Conn { get; set; }

    public Repository(IDapperContexto context)
    {
        Conn = context.Connection;
    }

    public dynamic Adicionar(TEntity entity, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null)
    {
        return entity == null ? null : Conn.Insert(entity, transaction, commandTimeout);
    }

    public bool Atualizar(TEntity entity, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null)
    {
        return entity != null && Conn.Update(entity, transaction, commandTimeout);
    }

    public bool Deletar(TEntity entity, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null)
    {
        return entity != null && Conn.Delete(entity, transaction, commandTimeout);
    }

    public TEntity ObterPorId(int id, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null)
    {
        return Conn.Get<TEntity>(id, transaction, commandTimeout);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> ObterTodos(IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null)
    {
        return Conn.GetList<TEntity>(null, null, transaction, commandTimeout);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> ObterPor(object where = null, object order = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null)
    {
        return Conn.GetList<TEntity>(@where);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

A interface IDapperContexto

```
 public interface IDapperContexto : IDisposable
{
    IDbConnection Connection { get; }
}
```

Classe DapperContexto que implementa a minha interface

```
public class DapperContexto : IDapperContexto
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private IDbConnection _connection;


    public DapperContexto()
    {
        _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    }

    public IDbConnection Connection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_connection == null)
            {
                _connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

            }
            if (_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                _connection.Open();
            }
            return _connection;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_connection != null && _connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            _connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Bom, feito isso achei que bastaria instanciar a classe Repositorio e passar nela o modelo que deveria persistir os dados, da seguinte forma:

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rec = new Repository<Customer>().ObterTodos();

        dgvData.DataSource = rec;
    }
```

Neste momento começaram as questões, lembrando que algumas características são importantes:
Banco de Dados SqlServer já existente com tabela de exemplo Customer
Usei Model Generator T4 para criar as classes baseadas no banco de dados, neste caso somente a tabela Customer

Ao instanciar a classe Repositorio recebo um erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então finalmente a dúvida é que eu não estou conseguindo passar parâmetro esperado, já que a classe está esperando um tipo IDapperContexto, algué tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: faltou informar `public Repository(IDapperContexto context)` DapperContexto no contrutor algo assim: `new Repositorio<Customer>(new DapperContexto())` mas, mesmo assim sua camada parece ter alguns problemas

Comment: Sinceramente eu abandonaria este código, tem tantos problemas nele que eu nem sei por onde começar. Sinto muito, mas há erros conceituais, mesmo consertando isto ainda terá problemas